# selenium Unable to locate tiktok caption

Tags: tiktok

After login into tiktok with selenium the selenium can't find the caption input field. my code is this

cap = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'public-DraftStyleDefault-block')
cap.send_key('this is test caption')

Error Is this

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".public-DraftStyleDefault-block"}
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.99)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x010EF243]
        (No symbol) [0x01077FD1]
        (No symbol) [0x00F6D04D]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9C0B0]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9C22B]
        (No symbol) [0x00FCE612]
        (No symbol) [0x00FB85D4]
        (No symbol) [0x00FCC9EB]
        (No symbol) [0x00FB8386]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9163C]
        (No symbol) [0x00F9269D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01389A22+2655074]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0137CA24+2601828]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01198C0A+619850]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01197830+614768]
        (No symbol) [0x010805FC]
        (No symbol) [0x01085968]
        (No symbol) [0x01085A55]
        (No symbol) [0x0109051B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7680FEF9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77357BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77357B8E+238]
```

How to fix this...

i try to automate tik tok video upload.

Comment: did you find answer yet?

Comment: no. Not yet. I Tried Every Possible option but not get the solution

Comment: did you tried yet to make ur code work on appium?

Comment: appium? what was that?

Comment: its emulator of phone